# call C# web service in php(elastix)

Tags: asterisk, elastix

i use agi programing in elastix that is base on php in my vm ware

i want to call C# web service in elastix(elastix is base on php)
this is my C# web service that return hello world

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;




  /// <summary>
  /// Summary description for WebService
  /// </summary>
  [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
  [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
  // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX,       
   [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
 public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

public WebService () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld() {
    return "Hello World";
}

}
```

and in my vm ware (elastix) i use :

```
$res=file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1:55194/WebSite2/WebService.asmx?op=HelloWorld");
$agi->verbose($res);
```

but it didn't show any thing,also i ping 127.0.0.1

i want to get hello world that return in web service please help me

Comment: I think you have to do a `POST`

Comment: can you give me an example because i didn't use post

Comment: You don't need post. Is the web service on the same machine as the vm because 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address. Try using the real ipaddress of the machine.

Comment: Ah well maybe not.  I just ran Fiddler on my web service, and it's using POST..  Maybe it supports either.

Comment: when i use real ip or name of the site it return html but i want to test it with my own local host and i change : http://localhost:55194/WebSite2/WebService.asmx   to http://(IP):55194/WebSite2/WebService.asmx  but page can not find

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you use AGI(agi is not elastix and can be any language,including C#) to access web  service.

If you need access web service, you can use function CURL in dialplan

If you need complex action to be done - you can write agi in c#.